# javax.mail unable to connect [ALERT] IOL RBL

Tags: java, email, imap

Good morning, I have this problem with javax.mail

When I am on windows everything works without giving any problems, on Linux however sometimes it throws this error javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] IOL RBL
precisely at the line Store#connect(host, mail, password)
while connecting to mail.

I have a program that has to check 2 times a day for some emails, sometimes it gives the error on some emails, and other times it gives the error on other emails.

Moreover, my Linux machine is not blacklisted since I've checked up.

Comment: The server has rejected you. What are you connecting to?  RBL sounds like a blacklist.

Comment: Hey @Max first of all, thanks for answering so fast. The issue is that sometimes the connection with the IMAP protocol works. It seems somewhat to be randomic.

Comment: Well, RBL usually means (DNS based) Realtime Blackhole List, which can change quite frequently.  That implies wherever you're running this code is not expected to connect to this server (though RBL usually applies to SMTP, not IMAP).  Unfortunately without knowing the server or operator, we're only guessing, and probably only the server operator can actually tell you why you were rejected.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to two Italian providers: 'Tiscali' and 'libero'; My VPS is hosted in Germany but that shouldn't really be a problem

Comment: If you are on a shared VPS the actions of other clients can get the network block out on block lists for some period of time. The security measures of mail hosts can be quite opaque

Comment: What do you recommend to do? I have over thousand emails